# Successfully implementing external classes in Eclipse. (Java)

Tags: java, eclipse, class, exception, external

I have been trying to use this external class folder which was given from my programming lecturer a few months back. I followed people's explanations of how to add via "configure build class", and the application somewhat recognises the class because a shortlist of some of the methods are given. It also does not return any errors prior to runtime but once it's ran I get this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Console
at lab3.q2.main(q2.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Console
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 1 more
```

This is really frustrating as it works from the linux computers in my college without issue. The class file is just a variation of the scanner that we use for user i/o, I have it attached.

[Console.class file](http://polya.computing.dcu.ie/ca165/faq/support/compiling/Console.class)

Comment: Make sure you use the same Java version than your college (`java -version`), this should sort it out.

Comment: just for curiosity, does eclipse's auto-completion (while typing) complete these methods?

Comment: @MouseEvent, yes it does.

Comment: you might need to make sure the class is also on the classpath for the run environment your compiled code is running in. can't tell from your description what that might exactly be.